# What is the type of a boost::extent object after providing dimensions?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

Say I have

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
using intArray3D = boost::multi_array<int, 3>;
```

and I want to create a bunch of `intArray3D`s with the same shape:

```
auto my_shape = boost::extents[3][4][5];
intArray3D xs(my_shape), ys(my_shape), zs(my_shape);
```

It's easy enough to use `auto` to assign `boost::extents[3][4][5]` into a variable, but how can I concretely figure out the underlying type?

Comment: Do you want to know it for the sake of curiosity, or do you want to then code something with that ?

Comment: In your case it's [`boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<3>`](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_array/blob/83c3738519a442c619f9ef661335acde6878b7d8/include/boost/multi_array/extent_gen.hpp#L28), but why do you care?

Comment: @Quentin Little of both, actually. I'm building a class that needs a couple such `multi_array`s of unknown-but-calculable size and I thought storing such an `extent` somewhere might make their construction easier. None of the ways I thought to store it worked (aside from `auto`) so my curiosity led me to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#extent_gen) mentions:

> `template gen_type<Ranges>::type`
>
> - This type generator is used to specify the result of `Ranges` chained calls to `extent_gen::operator[]`.

where `gen_type` is a member of `boost::multi_array_types::extent_gen` (and `boost::multi_array_types::extent_gen` is also the type of the global helper object `boost::extents`).

You can also see that constructors which accept a set of extents are specified in this way (at least for purposes of public documentation).  [For example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_class),

```
namespace boost {

template <typename ValueType, 
          std::size_t NumDims, 
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<ValueType> >
class multi_array {
```

...

```
  typedef multi_array_types::extent_gen         extent_gen;
```

...

```
  explicit multi_array(extent_gen::gen_type<NumDims>::type ranges,
                       const storage_order_type& store = c_storage_order(),
                       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

So you could rewrite that line of your code without using `auto` as:

```
boost::multi_array_types::extent_gen::gen_type<3>::type my_shape =
    boost::extents[3][4][5];
```

This is a bit silly for a local variable, but maybe you want to store a set of extents in a class or something like that.  If so, this is the way to do it according to the officially documented interface.

(As noted in comments, the actual type this typedef resolves to involves `boost::internal::`, but you should never use anything from an "internal" namespace in your code, because that is subject to change in future versions.)

Comment: I don't see why all the complication is necessary. The documentation clearly states that any container is allowed. That includes something like `std::array<>`. `extent_gen` is merely an internal type for syntactic sugar. (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596425/85371))

Comment: That's a very good point. I'm not that familiar with `multi_array`, and focused too much on the question about what `extents[3][4][5]` is without even looking at the actual arrays they're used for.

Comment: @sehe, the library authors must have been ambivalent to take any container for the sizes, so they kept and mainly documented boost::extents. The problem is that, first, it is an overkill, since only containers with a specific size are really allowed, second it would be hard to distinguish when the input container should interpreted as range to copy from (including other arrays) or the sizes for initialization. I struggled with that in my own library and at the end I settled for accepting this syntax multi::array({n, m, …}) and when possible detect ambiguity. or array({sizes},{}) at worst.

Answer (score 5):

Most importantly,

1. **you don't have to know**
2. you don't have to use `extents` either

Many things are acceptible as long they satisfy the [documented criteria](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_class):

[image]

The Collection concept is documented in [that link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/utility/Collection.html)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/949b4cec5b9c087d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using intArray3D = boost::multi_array<int, 3>;

void dump_shape(intArray3D const& arr) {
    for (unsigned dim = 0; dim < arr.dimensionality; ++dim)
        std::cout << arr.shape()[dim] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    {
        auto my_shape = boost::extents[3][4][5];
        intArray3D xs(my_shape), ys(my_shape), zs(my_shape);
        dump_shape(xs); dump_shape(ys); dump_shape(zs);
    }

    {
        std::array<int, 3> my_shape { 3, 4, 5 };
        intArray3D xs(my_shape), ys(my_shape), zs(my_shape);
        dump_shape(xs); dump_shape(ys); dump_shape(zs);
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> my_shape { 3, 4, 5 };
        intArray3D xs(my_shape), ys(my_shape), zs(my_shape);
        dump_shape(xs); dump_shape(ys); dump_shape(zs);
    }

}
```

Prints

```
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store a

```
template<class T>
using factory=std::function< T() >;
```

then when I want to create many arrays:

```
auto my_shape = boost::extents[3][4][5];
factory<intArray3D> shaper = [my_shape]{ return intArray3D(my_shape); };
intArray3D xs(shaper()), ys(shaper()), zs(shaper());
```

this eliminates dependence on the exact type of boost extents.